# How to Compute Space Complexity for Binary SubTree Finding

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-tree, space-complexity

This problem is from the book *Cracking the Coding Interview*. I have trouble understanding the space complexity of the solution.

**Problem:**
You have two very large binary trees: *T1*, with millions of nodes, and *T2*, with hundreds of nodes. Create an algorithm to decide if *T2* is a subtree of *T1*.

**Solution (in Java):**

```
public static boolean containsTree(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2) {
    if (t2 == null)
        return true; // The empty tree is a subtree of every tree.
    else
        return subTree(t1, t2);
}

/* Checks if the binary tree rooted at r1 contains the binary tree 
 * rooted at r2 as a subtree somewhere within it.
 */
public static boolean subTree(TreeNode r1, TreeNode r2) {
    if (r1 == null)
        return false; // big tree empty & subtree still not found.
    if (r1.data == r2.data) {
        if (matchTree(r1,r2)) return true;
    }
    return (subTree(r1.left, r2) || subTree(r1.right, r2)); 
}

/* Checks if the binary tree rooted at r1 contains the 
 * binary tree rooted at r2 as a subtree starting at r1.
 */
public static boolean matchTree(TreeNode r1, TreeNode r2) {
    if (r2 == null && r1 == null) 
        return true; // nothing left in the subtree
    if (r1 == null || r2 == null) 
        return false; //  big tree empty & subtree still not found
    if (r1.data != r2.data) 
        return false;  // data doesn’t match
    return (matchTree(r1.left, r2.left) && 
            matchTree(r1.right, r2.right));
}
```

The book says the **space complexity** of this solution is **O(log(n) +log(m))** where *m is the number of nodes in T1 (larger tree)* and *n number of nodes in T2*.

To me, it **appears that** the **solution has O(log(m)*log(n)) space complexity** since "subtree" function has log(n) recursive calls and each recursive call executes "matchTree" function which triggers log(m) recursive calls.

Why is this solution O(log(n) + log(m)) complexity?

Answer (score 5):

Since we're not creating any objects on the heap, the space complexity is the size of the stack. So the question is not how many total calls occur, but how big the stack can grow.

`containsTree()` can only call `subTree()`, `subTree()` can call itself or `matchTree()`, and `matchTree()` can only call itself. So at any point where `matchTree()` has been called, the stack looks like this:

```
[containsTree] [subTree] ... [subTree] [matchTree] ... [matchTree]
```

This is why you don't multiply the space complexities here: while each call to `subTree()` can call `matchTree()`, those calls to `matchTree()` leave the stack before `subTree()` continues recursing.

## Analysis along the lines of the "correct answer"

If the question doesn't specify if the trees are balanced, then a real worst-case analysis would assume they might not be. However, you and the book are assuming they are. We can set aside that question for later by saying the depth of *T1* is *c*, and the depth of *T2* is *d*. *c* is *O(log(m))* if *T1* is balanced, and *O(m)* otherwise. Same thing for *T2*'s *d*.

Worst case for `matchTree()` is *O(d)*, because the furthest it could recurse would be the height of *T2*.

Worst case for `subTree()` is *O(c)* for its recursion, because the furthest it could recurse would be the height of *T1*, plus the cost of calling `matchTree()`, for a total of *O(c+d)*.

And `containsTree()` just adds a constant on top of calling `subTree()`, so that doesn't change the space complexity.

So if both *T1* and *T2* are balanced, by replacing *c* and *d* you can see that *O(log(m)+log(n))* seems reasonable.

## Problems with the "correct answer"

Like I said before, it's not right to assume binary trees are balanced until you know for a fact that they are. So a better answer might be *O(m+n)*.

But wait! The question states that the size of *T2* is less than the size of *T1*. That means that *n* is *O(m)*, and *log(n)* is *O(log(m))*. So why have we been wasting time worrying about *n*?

If the trees are balanced, the space complexity is simply *O(log(m))*. In the general case where you don't know what's balanced or not, the real answer should be *O(m)*, the size of the larger tree.

Comment: hi Dan, for matchTree() by consulting the master theorem, we can say that matchtree  behaves like aT(n/2) + n  for n > 1, with a = 1. The master theorem states that if a < 2, then T(n) = O(n). The proof for this type of recurrence can be found at https://math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section5-2.pdf Also without much mathematical analysis, there is always a posibility that the binary tree is not balanced and all elements are "linline".. for a worst case scenario of O(n)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now, I'm trying to apply your explained logic to compute the space complexity of another similar problem and I'm still arriving at an answer that is different from the solution in the book. Can you take a look at the following problem and explain what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @JuanZamora `matchTree()` does not have a recurrence relation of *aT(n/2)+n*, because the stack space of `matchTree()` is a fixed constant, not a multiple of *n*. You're right that it becomes *O(n)* if the tree isn't balanced. Since jjwest and the book's author both considered it *O(log(n))*, I'm assuming somewhere in the book they say "the trees are balanced" and jjwest just forgot to write it?

Comment: @jjwest on StackOverflow it's best to ask new questions as new questions, not as edits to questions. Also, can you confirm that they state that the binary trees are balanced? Like Juan said, if a binary tree isn't balanced, worst-case it has a depth of *O(n)* (that is, it's equivalent to a linked list).

Comment: They don't explicitly tell us that trees are balanced but they assume it based on their solution. Thank you.